# webdriverio 'setValue' to an input field throws error InvalidElement State

Tags: javascript, jquery, selenium, mocha.js, webdriver-io

```
InvalidElementState An element command could not be completed because the element is in an invalid state (e.g. attempting to click a disabled element).
        invalid element state: Element must be user-editable in order to clear it.
```

> (Session info: chrome=49.0.2623.75)
>     (Driver info: chromedriver=2.21.371459 (36d3d07f660ff2bc1bf28a75d1cdabed0983e7c4),platform=Mac OS X 10.11.4 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
>   [09:49:15]:  ERROR  Unknown Remote end send an unknown status code.
>   RuntimeError: invalid element state: Element must be user-editable in order to clear it.

Screenshot:

[image]

This form is been implemented using jquery Text selector library .  is there any other way to set the Value ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case you should use below approach to `setValue` in `input` field :-

```
WebElement inputEl = driver.findElement(By.xpath("xPath exression"));
inputEl.click();
inputEl.sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL, "a"), Keys.DELETE, "valuet to set");
```

if you want to use `JavascriptExecutor`, try below approach :-

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
js.executeScript("arguments[0].click();arguments[0].value='';arguments[0].value=arguments[1];",inputEl,"valuet to set");
```

**Edited..**

You need to click on element before set value to enable this `input` if it's disappears..

Hope this will help you...:)

Comment: For SendKeys Option :  UnknownError An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command.
   unknown error: cannot focus element
  (Session info: chrome=49.0.2623.75)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.21.371459 (36d3d07f660ff2bc1bf28a75d1cdabed0983e7c4),platform=Mac OS X 10.11.4 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)

[08:52:36]:  ERROR Unknown Remote end send an unknown status code.

Comment: let me try second option -

Comment: Can you tell me element is enabled or not where you want to set value....as exception thrown.... it means there is no focus on this element...you need to click on this element before set value..

Comment: @Varam You are most welcome...If you are satisfied with answer, Please don't forget to accept the answer...:)